# Sort NSManagedObjects from closest to farthest from current location

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I have a Core Data model defined with two attributes

- (Double) latitude
- (Double) longitude

Now, I would like to fetched these objects and sort them depending on how far they are compared to the user's current location. I already know how to get the current location, but what I still can't figure out is how to sort the results depending on two attributes.

I've searched for something similar but I'm still a bit confused.

That'd be great if someone could point me to the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorting with a comparator block is quite easy

```
NSArray *positions = //all fetched positions
CLLocation *currentLocation   = // You said that you know how to get this.


positions = [positions sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id a, id b) {
    CLLocation *locationA    = [CLLocation initWithLatitude:a.latitude longitude:a.longitude];
    CLLocation *locationB    = [CLLocation initWithLatitude:b.latitude longitude:b.longitude];
    CLLocationDistance dist_a= [locationA distanceFromLocation: currentLocation];
    CLLocationDistance dist_b= [locationB distanceFromLocation: currentLocation];
    if ( dist_a < dist_b ) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if ( dist_a > dist_b) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }
}
```

As I just learned from lnafziger, you should add that useful hack/workaround¹, he is showing, to this.

---

¹<sub>choose form this words the one, that has the most positive connotation for you</sub>

Comment: +1 great way to do this!  Please look at my answer though about the bug in distanceFromLocation and a workaround to get the correct value.

Comment: I saw it, but I didnt want to steal it :)

Comment: Steal away.  I prefer "workaround" rather than hack though, lol.  :)

Comment: for me a "hack" is a small yet elegant solution, where as "workaround" is something that I do and hate, as the marketing guys have forced a deadline, I am about to crack.

Comment: Haha, and I figure that I am working around a bug that Apple has...  No worries, just making a joke more than anything!

Comment: @lnafziger, see my edit for a solution about hack/workaround.

Comment: Ok, I tried it once with 3 pins and it works. One might say it's enough :). Thanks for your great answer.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to convert you long/lat pairs into a geographical distance between points and then sort on that single attribute.

Here's an article on some conversion methods, depending on what approximations you want to accept: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't.

Not just by sorting lat/long by itself anyway.  :)

You will need to have a property that contains the distance from your current location.  You can do this by adding a transient property which is calculated as needed or creating another array with the distances (probably easier).

To calculate your distance from your current location, use this method:

```
CLLocation *currentLocation   = // You said that you know how to get this.
CLLocation *storedLocation    = [CLLocation initWithLatitude:object.latitude 
                                                   longitude:object.longitude];
/*
 * Calculate distance in meters
 * Note that there is a bug in distanceFromLocation and it gives different
 * values depending on whether you are going TO or FROM a location. 
 * The correct distance is the average of the two:
 */
CLLocationDistance *distance1 = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:storedLocation];
CLLocationDistance *distance2 = [storedLocation distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];
CLLocationDistance *distance  = distance1 / 2 + distance2 / 2;
```

Comment: I'm intrigued as to why you need to calculate twice the distance between the two locations and then do distance1 / 2 + distance2 / 2. Could you tell me why ?

Comment: Try it:  Calculate the distance from location1 to location2 and compare it to the distance from location2 to location1.  They are different.  (It is a known bug in distanceFromLocation.)  Oddly enough, the average **is** the correct value though.

Comment: I would definitely combine my answer with @TDeBailleul to get the best solution for this!